# how to open extension when web page button is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to open the chrome extension when external web page button is clicked . when i click the web page button then extension is opened without clicking the browser extension button. I searched very deeply but could not find any thing.
If any one can help to find my solution?

Comment: Use the upcoming [sidePanel API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel/).

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a content script into the webpage that listens for a click event on the button.

Once the button is clicked, the content script can send a message to the background script of the extension using the `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` API

```
// content.js

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Send a message to the background script to open the extension
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'openExtension'});
});
```

The background script can then respond by opening the extension using `chrome.tabs.create` with the extension's URL

```
// background.js
// Listen for messages from the content script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.action === 'openExtension') {
        chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: 'popup.html' });
        chrome.browserAction.getPopup({}, function (popupUrl) {
            if (popupUrl) {
                chrome.windows.create({
                    url: popupUrl,
                    type: 'popup',
                    width: 400,
                    height: 600,
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Add these scripts as well as `activeTab` permission to your manifest file

```
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "runtime"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://...."],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for help. but i want to open extension on same chrome tab on right side

Comment: this is not working this gives an error " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendMessage')".

Comment: Has the content script been injected in your page? (see content_scripts in the manifest file)

Comment: yes. content script has been injected

Comment: Can you change the "background" object in manifest to   

"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253623/discussion-between-maryam-aftab-and-callback).